# Is there a way to plot a function f with equations (from a ODE system) inside of it?

Tags: matlab, math, differential-equations, ode45

I am trying to solve this assignment for my Differential Equations class and I am encountering some problems.

Given this system of ODEs:

```
dy(1) = y(2) − y(3);
dy(2) = −3*y(2) − 5*sin(ω*y(1));
dy(3) = y(1)*y(2);
```

with `omega=3`. Initial values: `y(1)=0; y(2)=4; y(3)=1;`

Plot `f` between `t=0` and `t=20`:

```
f(t) = |2*cos(y1(t)) + y2(t)|
```

I have first tried simulating the equation system with ODE45 with this code:

On editor:

```
function dy=modelo10(t,y)
    global omega

    dy = zeros(3,1);
    dy(1)= y(2) - y(3);
    dy(2)= -3*y(2) - 5*sin(omega*y(1));
    dy(3)= y(1)*y(2);

end
```

On command tab:

```
>>global omega;
>>omega = 3;
>>[T,Y] = ode45(@modelo10, [0,20], [0,4,1]); 
%% I assign the function to variable f
>>f = @(t) 2.*cos(y(:,1)) + y(:,2);
%% And finally plot it with the values t
>>fplot(f, [0,20]);
```

I get a blank graph with the following error:

```
Warning: Function behaves unexpectedly on array inputs. To improve 
performance, properly
vectorize your function to return an output with the same size and 
shape as the input
arguments. 
  In matlab.graphics.function.FunctionLine>getFunction
  In matlab.graphics.function.FunctionLine/updateFunction
  In matlab.graphics.function.FunctionLine/set.Function_I
  In matlab.graphics.function.FunctionLine/set.Function
  In matlab.graphics.function.FunctionLine
  In fplot>singleFplot (line 241)
  In fplot>@(f)singleFplot(cax,{f},limits,extraOpts,args) (line 196)
  In fplot>vectorizeFplot (line 196)
  In fplot (line 166) 
Warning: Error updating FunctionLine.

The following error was reported evaluating the function in 
FunctionLine update:
Non-scalar in Uniform output, at index 1, output 1.
Set 'UniformOutput' to false.

Warning: Error updating FunctionLine.

The following error was reported evaluating the function in 
FunctionLine update:
Non-scalar in Uniform output, at index 1, output 1.
Set 'UniformOutput' to false
```

So my question is what are the steps (or commands) to plot `f`?

I am using MATLAB R2019a.

Answer (score 4):

Your first problem is in defining `f`:

```matlab
[T,Y] = ode45(@modelo10, [0,20], [0,4,1]); 
f = @(t) 2.*cos(y(:,1)) + y(:,2);
```

Note that the first line defines a variable `Y`, but in the second one you use `y`. These are different variables. This likely works for you because you have a variable `y` defined in your workspace, but it is doing the wrong thing.

Next, your `f` is a function `f(t)`, but it is defined not using the input `t`. It always outputs the same thing. `fplot` expects a function that outputs an array of the same size as its input, this is the error message you are getting.

However, you don't need to define a function here, you can directly compute all values for `f` and plot them using `plot`:

```matlab
[t,y] = ode45(@modelo10, [0,20], [0,4,1]);
f = 2.*cos(y(:,1)) + y(:,2);
plot(t,f)
```

---

Additionally, I want to recommend that you don't use `global`. You don't need it here, you can define `omega` as an input argument to `modelo10`:

```matlab
function dy = modelo10(t,y,omega)
   dy = zeros(3,1);
   dy(1) = y(2) - y(3);
   dy(2) = -3*y(2) - 5*sin(omega*y(1));
   dy(3) = y(1)*y(2);
end
```

and then call `ode45` as follows:

```matlab
[t,y] = ode45(@(t,y)modelo10(t,y,omega), [0,20], [0,4,1]);
```

Here, `@(t,y)modelo10(t,y,omega)` defines an anonymous function that carries the value of `omega` with it. This anonymous function has two input arguments (`t` and `y`), as required by `ode45`.

Finally, you can simplify your code by defining `modelo10` on a single line:

```matlab
function dy = modelo10(t,y,omega)
   dy = [ y(2) - y(3); -3*y(2) - 5*sin(omega*y(1)); y(1)*y(2) ];
end
```

You can now do:

```matlab
modelo10 = @(t,y) [ y(2) - y(3); -3*y(2) - 5*sin(omega*y(1)); y(1)*y(2) ];
[t,y] = ode45(modelo10, [0,20], [0,4,1]);
```

Comment: Thanks you're a life saver!

Answer (score 2):

```
global omega;
omega = 3;

[T,Y] = ode45(@modelo10, [0,20], [0,4,1]);
```

- From here Y is a function of T --> No need to define new function
  Y = Y(T) for T = [0,20], this is no longer variable but real numbers
  Y = [Y1(0),..., Y1(20); Y2(0),..., Y2(20); Y3(0),..., Y3(20)]
- I assign the function to variable f

  ```
  f = @(t) 2.*cos(y(:,1)) + y(:,2) --> f = abs( 2.*cos(Y(:,1)) + Y(:,2));
  ```

  lowercase y and UPPERCASE Y are two  different variables.
  Absolute value function in matlab is abs
- And finally plot it with the values t

  ```
  Use plot instead of fplot
  ```

  Actually you don't need to specify input value for function f as it has 
  been already included when calculating ode45 whereas fplot takes a key 
  argument, namely, function expression

  ```
  (function handle --> function defined as follow f = @(x)_____).
  ```

  The input could be additionally added as second argument.

  It's optional; by default fplot evaluates function in the range [0 5]
- Here f is real number not function expression, it has been already evaluated

  ```
      plot(T, f);
  ```

[image]
      Function f Plot for T ranging from 0 to 20